# Android Insert text inside analog clock

Tags: android, clock

I have created an analog clock and now I want to add text inside it. This is my main.xml. I can add text to the textview but that appears above or below the clock and not inside it. Is there a way to add text inside the clock? I checked AnalogClock class on android and I do not see any such option

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/analog_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock"
       android:text="@string/analog_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Niko`'s answer is completely correct, but in case you don't want to use `FrameLayout`, all you have to do is using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, check the below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="YouText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks William, Even this takes care of my issue. Btw I have asked another question in the above comment. Can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both inside `FrameLayout` or u can use `RelativeLayout` also:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/analog_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/analog_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: **+1 for you**.There is no need to put `android:text` for `AnalogClock`, also you have to put `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and
 `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the `FrameLayout`

Comment: Yes of course the needed schemas, but it's not said this is the root view =)

Comment: Wow..that was pretty easy..Thanks Niko and William. I have one more question if you guys dont mind answering. I am using an image for the clock dial since I want a custom image for the clock. But now the problem is imposing the text on the image inside the dial. How do I do it? Do I need to make the image transparent to see the text inside it?

Comment: @fzansari all you need to do is putting `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"` in the `AnalogClock`. If you mean something else, kindly explain more

Comment: William, I have some text in my textview if you see above. android:text="@string/analog_label". When I add an image for the dial like this android:dial="@drawable/dial_pad", I dont see the text anymore. I tried what you suggested i.e tried making the image as background but even then the text is not visible

Comment: @fzansari you are doing something wrong, adding background image doesn't hide your text. please start a new question and tag me maybe i can help.